# "This repository indicated that all its packages are repository signed; however, this package is unsigned." on Jetbrains RIder

Tags: c#, macos, nuget, nuget-package, rider

Every time i try to update a nuget from "package" tab on rider for mac, i receive the following message:

> "[Notification][Install] Install failed (project: xxx, package:
>   Xamarin.Forms v4.1.0.581479) Package restore failed. Rolling back
>   package changes for xxx".

Opening the log tab, it seems to be a signing issue of packages from 'https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json'.

I'm running Jetbrains Rider 2019.1.3 (with 2019.1.2 too), on macos Mojave. The same process works on nuget package tool on VS for Mac.

If I run the restore and add command manually on package console, it doesn't fail.

This is the message that for instance i receive in NuGet log tab when trying to update Xamarin.Forms nuget:

> NU3004: Package 'Xamarin.Forms 4.1.0.581479' from source
>   'https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json': This repository indicated that
>   all its packages are repository signed; however, this package is
>   unsigned. Package restore failed. Rolling back package changes for
>   'xxx'. NuGet.PackageManagement.PackageReferenceRollbackException:
>   Package restore failed. Rolling back package changes for 'xxx'.   at
>   NuGet.PackageManagement.NuGetPackageManager.ExecuteBuildIntegratedProjectActionsAsync
>   (NuGet.ProjectManagement.Projects.BuildIntegratedNuGetProject
>   buildIntegratedProject, System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable1[T]
>   nuGetProjectActions, NuGet.ProjectManagement.INuGetProjectContext
>   nuGetProjectContext, System.Threading.CancellationToken token)
>   [0x00c45] in <7a2d2afbbb674cd48052281699c39e01>:0    at
>   NuGet.PackageManagement.NuGetPackageManager.ExecuteNuGetProjectActionsAsync
>   (NuGet.ProjectManagement.NuGetProject nuGetProject,
>   System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable1[T] nuGetProjectActions,
>   NuGet.ProjectManagement.INuGetProjectContext nuGetProjectContext,
>   NuGet.Protocol.Core.Types.PackageDownloadContext downloadContext,
>   System.Threading.CancellationToken token) [0x00121] in
>   <7a2d2afbbb674cd48052281699c39e01>:0    at
>   NuGet.PackageManagement.NuGetPackageManager.InstallPackageAsync
>   (NuGet.ProjectManagement.NuGetProject nuGetProject,
>   NuGet.Packaging.Core.PackageIdentity packageIdentity,
>   NuGet.PackageManagement.ResolutionContext resolutionContext,
>   NuGet.ProjectManagement.INuGetProjectContext nuGetProjectContext,
>   NuGet.Protocol.Core.Types.PackageDownloadContext downloadContext,
>   System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable1[T] primarySources,
>   System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable1[T] secondarySources,
>   System.Threading.CancellationToken token) [0x00121] in
>   <7a2d2afbbb674cd48052281699c39e01>:0    at
>   NuGet.PackageManagement.NuGetPackageManager.InstallPackageAsync
>   (NuGet.ProjectManagement.NuGetProject nuGetProject,
>   NuGet.Packaging.Core.PackageIdentity packageIdentity,
>   NuGet.PackageManagement.ResolutionContext resolutionContext,
>   NuGet.ProjectManagement.INuGetProjectContext nuGetProjectContext,
>   System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable1[T] primarySources,
>   System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable1[T] secondarySources,
>   System.Threading.CancellationToken token) [0x000d3] in
>   <7a2d2afbbb674cd48052281699c39e01>:0    at
>   JetBrains.ProjectModel.NuGet.Operations.NuGetInstallOperation+<>c__DisplayClass5_0.b__0
>   (NuGet.ProjectManagement.NuGetProject nuGetProject,
>   System.Threading.CancellationToken token) [0x000a5] in
>   :0    at
>   JetBrains.ProjectModel.NuGet.Operations.NuGetInstallOperation.InstallInternal
>   (JetBrains.ProjectModel.IProject project, System.String packageId,
>   System.String packgeUserStr,
>   JetBrains.ProjectModel.NuGet.Configs.NuGetFeedContext feedContext,
>   System.Int32 nestedLevel,
>   JetBrains.ProjectModel.NuGet.Logging.NuGetNotificationMode mode,
>   JetBrains.ProjectModel.NuGet.Operations.NuGetOperationReporter
>   reporter, System.Func`3[T1,T2,TResult] nativeInstall) [0x003e6] in
>   :0

The command `nuget trusted-signers list` shows me

> There are no trusted signers.

I tried to forcibly include nuget.org as trusted signers in ~/.config/NuGet/NuGet.Config file with the command `nuget trusted-signers Add -Name nuget.org` but the issue remains.

Someone has any ideas?

Comment: It looks like a bug in Rider. Could you please create an issue in the official Rider tracker: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/RIDER Please, attach the full log from the NuGet log tab, and the content of ~/.config/NuGet/NuGet.Config and ~/.nuget/NuGet/NuGet.Config

Comment: Fine, i'll be able to do so this evening. Thx in advance.

Comment: Done -> https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RIDER-30213

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a native bug in NuGet (see https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/7574). You experienced this bug (https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RIDER-30213) in Rider 2019.1 because it uses NuGet 4.9 (without the bugfix).
In Rider 2019.2, the internal NuGet version was bumped up to 5.2; now the bug is fixed.